# Clarify on SharePoint user license count

Tags: user-profile-service, ups, license

We are using SharePoint on-premise. Our company only have 100 users (I count it manually...). But the UPS in SharePoint CA shows we have about 300 profiles. I checked there are many service accounts or test accounts sync into UPS.

My question is how many user CAL we required? I have no control on the domain so I have to sync all 300 users/non-users into UPS.

Comment: Emm, does SharePoint Server (on-premise) have user account limits? I supposed it's only for office365 plans. You may filter which accounts (by OU and attributes) to be synced in AD connection settings in UPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need 100. You only license users who actually use the product.

Comment: If Microsoft come to my office and investigate, how can we prove the 100?

Comment: They'll tell you how to determine the count. You can argue with them, at that point.

Comment: So the number of account is not the point. The point is we have how many human?

Comment: The point is how many people use SharePoint. You must follow the guidelines you receive in an audit about how to count that. From there, you can argue your point about what is valid and what isn't with them.